# Why aren't Inno Setup and NSIS in my Visual & Installer menu?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, visual-and-installer

I recently installed (and registered) Inno Setup, Visual & Installer, Graphical Installer Wizard, and NSIS on my PC. For some reason, though, the V & I extensions menu in VS 2019 *doesn't display the options for Inno Setup and NSIS, much less their submenus. **What's wrong?!*** What's more, I need to know if the Inno Setup process/editor/wizard automatically detects and accounts for a program's dependency files and prerequisites. (It would be tedious to have to find and add them all manually.)

Comment: This sounds like two different questions to me. It might be best to break the second query out into it's own discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for first part:

Starting from Visual Studio 2019, all extensions menus previously located in the Main menu were moved under the **Extensions** menu.

[image: Extensions menu]

To clarify: This is a change in Visual Studio SDK = **Microsoft** changed how the extensions behave, this change applies to any extension, not only V&I.

This change also affects the *Graphical Installer Wizard* submenus and items (they are not present in VS 2019) so you need to launch them from GI NSIS/ Inno Setup installation directory (it is an Wizard.exe file).

As many people are complaining on this change, there is an extension which can change that to pre-2019 behavior: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Evgeny.RestoreExtensions#overview

Second part:

Inno Setup *does not* detect dependencies automatically, you need to do that manually.

There are many scripts already doing that, simply copy them, for example: [How to detect and install prerequisite(s) using Inno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208765/how-to-detect-and-install-prerequisites-using-inno)

Comment: It is interesting that "ResOrg" still manages to list elsewhere in the menu. Must be a loophole!

Comment: What is ResOrg? To achieve pre-2019 behavior use the extension mentioned above.

Comment: See: https://www.riverblade.co/products/resorg/ It has standalone app and IDE extension.

Comment: Concerning the ResOrg menu location, they said to me: "Re the “Extensions” menu - that menu was added in VS2019, but previous versions used "Tools". As the ResOrg VS plugin source is common to all versions, the commands are added to the Tools menu."